# Avoid push/addToSet null value to mongodb array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When using **$push** or **$addToSet** operator in mongoose, and the value I give (**friend.id**) is **null** or **undefined**, it will push a **null** element to the array.

```
dbUser.findByIdAndUpdate(
 _id,
 {
  $addToSet: {
  'friendsBlackList': friendB.id ,
  'FriendsWhiteList': friendW.id ,
  },
  },
  { new: true, upsert: true }
});
```

How to avoid pushing a null element? Can it be controlled in the mongoose schema? Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Why can't you check the value of `friend.id` before issuing the query?

Comment: Yes, but What if there are two push operations? I updated my question

Comment: @Sulliwane You still didn't answer the question. It seems like the easiest way to do this is to check if the values you want to push are null beforehand.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg because I have two fields in the push operation, and sometimes friendB.id is null, but friendW.id is not. So even if I check the value beforehand, I cannot skip the operation (or it won't push the value that is not null). But maybe I should just split my push operations in two...so I can check value as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mongoose and its syntax, but what your describing can be done with the following pseudocode:

```
var update = { $addToSet:{}};
if(friendB.id !=null){
    update.$addToSet.friendsBlackList = friendB.id
}
if(friendW.id !=null){
    update.$addToSet.friendsWhiteList = friendW.id
}

dbUser.findByIdAndUpdate(_id,update,{ new: true, upsert: true });
```

Some drivers (ie Morphia) have options you can set to ignore null and empty values. You should check if Mongoose has such options as well.